# connexion API : config for dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, connexion

I'm trying to find a way to configure my connexion app.
I want to be able to inject a variable that can affect the behavior of the operations associated to a route.

At first, I tried to use the MethodResolver so I could pass class_argument to inject dependencies but I prefer to keep explicit routing with clear operationId. (plus I have multiple /foooo/bar/{id} routes and the doc is no clear on how I should manage it : FooooView ? BarView in foo-oo module ?)

For now the operationId functions call a const which is an instance of a class to which I can give new parameters if my code evolves.

```py
class ApiDependencies:

   def __init__(self, criteria_collection):
       self.criteria_collection = criteria_collection

criteria_collection = init_default_criteria_collection()

dependencies = ApiDependencies(criteria_collection)
```

```py
from controller.api.dependencies_injection import dependencies

def status():
   return "Criteria : " + criteria_collection, 200
```

but for testing for example, I would like to be able to give this parameters directly to the app itself and access it in my operationId function.

```py
app = AsyncApp(__name__)
app.add_api(
     "api.yaml",
      resolver=RelativeResolver("controller.api.routes"),
      config={criteria_collection : criteria_collection}
)
```

```py
def status():
    return "Criteria : " + connexion.config.criteria_collection, 200
```

Is it possible ? Did I miss something in the doc ?
Thanks for your help